# Error while loading shared libraries

Tags: wine, ubuntu-16.04

I installed Wine from WineHQ for my Ubuntu 16.04 machine and I get the following error:

`/opt/wine-stable/bin/wine: error while loading shared libraries: libwine.so.1: cannot create shared object descriptor: Operation not permitted.`

Comment: seer https://www.pcsuggest.com/install-wine-ubuntu/

Answer (score 6):

Short answer – run this:

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.mmap_min_addr=0
```

Longer answer:

I ran into exactly the same error a day ago after upgrading *from* Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 (and re-installing wine-staging from WineHQ).

I was able to work out that it only happened when trying to run a 32-bit Windows executable via Wine (on a 64-bit system).

After way too much debugging, I got a clue from trying to run the Wine notepad.exe under `strace`:

```
$ strace /usr/bin/wine notepad.exe
execve("/usr/bin/wine", ["/usr/bin/wine", "notepad.exe"], 0x7ffc266e8478 /* 55 vars */) = 0
strace: [ Process PID=19507 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
brk(NULL)                               = 0x7c423000

[ … 140 lines snipped … ]

openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/wine-staging/lib/libwine.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\220d\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1832828, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
close(3)                                = 0
writev(2, [{iov_base="/opt/wine-staging/bin/wine", iov_len=26}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="error while loading shared libra"..., iov_len=36}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="libwine.so.1", iov_len=12}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="cannot create shared object desc"..., iov_len=38}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="Operation not permitted", iov_len=23}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 10/opt/wine-staging/bin/wine: error while loading shared libraries: libwine.so.1: cannot create shared object descriptor: Operation not permitted
) = 144
exit_group(127)                         = ?
+++ exited with 127 +++
```

The crucial bit is the `mmap2` failure. After reading [the `mmap2` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap2.2.html) (and then [the `mmap` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)), it seemed like it was just trying to map an anonymous block of 8192 bytes – not even linked to a file on disk. That seemed extremely boring and not the sort of thing that should fail.

So I thought I'd investigate the `sysctl` settings to see if there was anything that might've been changed in my Ubuntu 16.04 → 18.04 upgrade, in particular anything that might affect `mmap2` or just `mmap`.

I found a likely candidate in `/etc/sysctl.d/10-zeropage.conf`:

```
# Protect the zero page of memory from userspace mmap to prevent kernel
# NULL-dereference attacks against potential future kernel security
# vulnerabilities.  (Added in kernel 2.6.23.)
#
# While this default is built into the Ubuntu kernel, there is no way to
# restore the kernel default if the value is changed during runtime; for
# example via package removal (e.g. wine, dosemu).  Therefore, this value
# is reset to the secure default each time the sysctl values are loaded.
vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536
```

The main reason this seemed a strong candidate is because it mentioned Wine.

After that, I found this page on the WineHQ Wiki: [Preloader Page Zero Problem](https://wiki.winehq.org/Preloader_Page_Zero_Problem).

While that page doesn't *explicitly* mention the error we encountered, it mentioned a lot of other things that sounded suspiciously related.

So I tried its recommendation for “the right workaround”, i.e., `sudo sysctl -w vm.mmap_min_addr=0` – and suddenly I could run Windows 32-bit apps under Wine again! :-)

NOTE: The WineHQ Wiki page also gives instructions for making that change permanent, though there may be some system security implications if you do so.

Comment: Well, this worked for me.